# Foreign Key Issue?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mysql-connector

In my HomeController, I am having trouble with my create function accessing the database. After submitting the form in my browser, this is the error that shows:

***Error Given***

MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`petshelterdb`.`pets`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Pets_Owners_OwnerId` FOREIGN KEY (`OwnerId`) REFERENCES `owners` (`OwnerId`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in ResultSet.cs, line 49

I am not using a login/registration. The idea is that I have a "bulletin board" that shows pets that can be adopted and owners that can adopt. A new pet or owner can be added to the board. If I select the owner's name, I can have that owner "adopt" a pet on the board. I designated in the HomeController code which line is the issue.

Since I'm not working with a UserId, I'm not sure how to go about this.

***Pet.cs***

```csharp
namespace petShelter.Models
{
    public class Pet
    {
        [Key]
        public int PetId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Skill1 { get; set; }
        public string Skill2 { get; set; }
        public string Skill3 { get; set; }


        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public Owner Owner { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

***Owner.cs***

```csharp
namespace petShelter.Models
{
    public class Owner
    {
        [Key]
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }


        List<Pet> MyPets { get; set; }

        public string FullName()
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }

    }
}
```

***HomeController.cs***

```csharp
 [HttpPost("/pet/new")]
        public IActionResult Create(Pet newPet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(newPet);
                _context.SaveChanges(); ***THIS IS WHERE ISSUE OCCURS***
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = newPet.PetId });
            }
            else
            {
                if (newPet.Name == null)
                {
                    ModelState.TryAddModelError("Name", "The Name field is required");
                }
                return View("NewPet", newPet);
            }
        }
```

***PetShelterContext.cs***

```csharp
namespace petShelter.Models
{
    public class PetShelterContext : DbContext
    {
        public PetShelterContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the entity definition, OwnerId is required. So you have to specify OwnerId that actually exists in the database when you are adding the Pet record.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: @arunes So the field OwnerId needs to be designated as [Required] but PetId does not?

Comment: @Sergey - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version=5.0.5

Comment: When you are listing pets,  there are no owners but your DB schema requires it.  Perhaps create a record in Owner table ownerid =0 ownername ="unadopted".  When you create a pet record for the pet to be adopted,  pass on 0 for ownerid.  When the pet is adopted, replace ownerid with the id of the real owner.

Comment: @Sergey - Thank you! That fixed that issue and now when I read it, it makes sense. 
Conclusion: I do not have an Owner created yet, therefore the OwnerId for the pet I created shows up null in the database. After I create an owner and have owner "adopt" the pet, then the pet will show OwnerId.

Comment: Yes , you are right. After creating owner you can assign  OwnerId of the pet. Or on the     contrary add pet to the owher - owner.Pets=new List<Pet>(). owher.Pets.Add(pet);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
public int OwnerId { get; set; }
```

with

```
public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
```

and fix properties ( the attributes are optional for net5)

```
public class Owner
    {
        .......

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Pet.Owner))]
        public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
       
        .....
}
```

and maybe here too

```
public class Pet
    {
        .....

   public int OwnerId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey(nameof(OwnerId))]
    [InverseProperty("Pets")]
   public Owner Owner { get; set; }
     
    }
```